# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL' error after importing Vue module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

I created Vue2 app where I imported a module into `Home.vue`. I want 3D model (`BaseModel.vue`) to show on the screen.  When I run the app then the following error shows up:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL'
> on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
> at eval (DRACOLoader.js?0ca5:292:1)

And now, when I remove (or comment out) that module (`Projection2D.vue`) and leave just `BaseModel.vue` alone then my code works fine and there are no errors. I was digging in trying to figure out what's happening and found that the issue is most likely caused by the manner in which packages are imported to the module `Projection2D.vue`. Here is my code:

**BaseModel.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="viewport" ref="container"></div>
</template>


<script>
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'

export default {
  name: 'Scene',

  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      light: null,
      light2: null,
      mesh: null,
      controls: null,
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init() {

        this.width = this.$el.offsetWidth
        this.height = this.$el.offsetHeight

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color('#272727');

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.width / this.height, 0.01, 10);
        this.camera.position.set(0,0,0.2);

        // renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
        this.$refs.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        // geometries
        let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
        let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.mesh.position.x = 0.1
        this.scene.add(this.mesh);

        // lights
        this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,2);
        this.light.position.set(1,1,1);
        this.scene.add(this.light);

        this.light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,2);
        this.light2.position.set(-1,1,-1);
        this.scene.add(this.light2);

        // orbit controls
        this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        this.controls.update();

        // DRACOLoader
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('dracoDecoder/');

        // GLTFLoader
        const modelLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        modelLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

        modelLoader.load(
            "Avocado.glb",
            // called when the resource is loaded
            (glb) => {
            console.log(glb)
            this.scene.add(glb.scene);
            },
            // called while loading is progressing
            function (xhr) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
            },
            // called when loading has errors
            function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            }
        );
    },

    resizeCanvas() {

        this.width = this.$el.offsetWidth
        this.height = this.$el.offsetHeight

        // Update camera
        this.camera.aspect = this.width / this.height
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

        // Update renderer
        this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height)
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    },


    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.controls.update();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
      this.animate();

      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
          this.resizeCanvas();
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="pa-0 mt-1">
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <div>
          <BaseModel />
          <Projection2D />
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import BaseModel from '../components/model3D/BaseModel.vue'
import Projection2D from '../components/Projection2D.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  components: {
    BaseModel,
    Projection2D // if I remove this module here and in template then it works fine
  },

}
</script>
```

**Projection2D.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="zimW"></div>
</template>

<script>
require('@danzen/createjs');
const makeZIM = require('zimjs');
const zim = makeZIM();  // if I remove this line then it throw abovementioned error

import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
name: "Projection2D",

data() {
    return {
     width: 800,
     height: 350,
     frame: null
    }
},

computed: {
    ...mapState('model2D', ['modelLength', 'modelWidth', 'regalsTotalNumber', 'regalsModulesHorizontal']),
    ...mapGetters('model2D', ['scaledLength', 'scaledWidth'])

},

methods: {

    updateStage() {
        this.frame.stage.update();
    },

    disposeChildren() {
        this.frame.stage.disposeAllChildren();  
    },

},

mounted() {
   
const scaling = "zimW";
const width = this.width;
const height = this.height;

const color = purple;

this.frame = new Frame({ scaling, width, height, color, allowDefault: true });
this.frame.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready from ZIM Frame");

    const stage = this.frame.stage;
    const stageW = this.frame.width;
    const stageH = this.frame.height;
 
    stage.update();

});

}

}

</script>
```

I use 2D library called ZIM.js (https://zimjs.com/). For some reasons I can't use CDN as a source, that's why I installed library through npm. Don't know why I can't just import that package from node module, docs on the site suggests CDN or sth like this:

```
require('@danzen/createjs');
const makeZIM = require('zimjs');
const zim = makeZIM();
```

and you can see I used this pattern in my code. Unfortunatley this makes my code not working.
I tried this:

```
import * as zim from 'zimjs'
import * as createjs from '@danzen/createjs'
```

but it doesn't work. Honestly, I don't know how to solve this issue. I'm not sure if `require` is the problem here. Anyways, if I comment out this chunk of code I can upload my 3D model. Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL' when loading .glb model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956818/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url-when-loading-glb-model)

Comment: @Rabbid76 no, it's not. This is topic I created yesterday but today I created new one, which explains everything from new perspective after doing more research.

Comment: So why do you not edit the original question? Why do you try t attract attention with a new question?

Comment: The [documentation for Zim](https://zimjs.com/npm.html) explains certain steps that must be taken for using Zip from npm, including using browserify. Did you follow those instructions? Otherwise, it looks like you're trying to use the [modules](https://zimjs.com/es6.html#MODULES) method without understanding it. But then it looks like Vue might encourage that because the code shown uses `import` in a `<script>` without `type="module"`...

Comment: @Rabbid76 because I would have to totally change the question. And edited the whole post from the beginning, even the subject.

Comment: @mustafa00 Yes, that's the way to go. At least delete the old question if it's no longer needed.

Comment: OK, it's deleted